# Computer stuck on "Getting Windows Ready" while installation from usb

Tags: dual-boot, usb-installation

So this is my first time getting into Linux and I created a bootable USB drive to install it. I then restarted my computer to begin the installation process and it is stuck on the blue screen saying "Getting Windows ready Don't turn off your computer". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The message you are getting is not from Ubuntu or Linux, but from Windows, which I presume is already installed on your computer. A quick Google search shows many discussions about this "stuck on blue screen" issue, but this is not the place to discuss them.

**Your problem is that when you restarted your computer, it did not boot into your USB key.**

You need to find a way to make your computer boot your USB key:

- Maybe you can press a key (such as F10 or F12) at the very start, only available for a very short time, that displays a menu of all bootable devices; you should find your USB key in there.
- You may need to access your computer BIOS (using another key at computer startup, such as Esc, F2, etc.) to enable boot from USB devices, or to give higher priority to USB devices (above the internal hard drive).

This is very dependent on the precise computer you are using (brand and model). It is also dependent on the way you created the USB key (which tool you used, and whether this is a legacy boot key or a more modern UEFI boot key).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Ubuntu issue.  This usually means your computer is performing an update.  In Windows 10, which it sounds like you have, there is no provided way to stop your computer from performing updates.  It sounds like the windows update service started downloading and/or installing one in the background while you were making your USB stick.  The Windows update service will prevent your computer from shutting down while it's running, because Microsoft insists on being able to update your computer whether you want them to or not.  Unfortunately this is just part of the beast when dealing with Windows 10.

If you want control of your computer's updates back in Windows then you can:

1. Use method 3 [here](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-disable-windows-update-in-windows-10/) to disable the Windows update service.  Despite what it says, it's not permanent because then you...
2. Download [Windows Update Mini Tool](https://wumt.blogspot.ca/2016/11/windows-update-minitool.html) - when you run it it will re-enable the service and then take control of it to allow you to perform which updates you want when and how you want.

Note that the tool will automatically start the service, but it won't automatically turn it off.  So you either need to manually turn off the service after you run the tool (as per step one above), use a script that will do it for you.  I wrote one that you can find on page six of the English support thread for wumt on Wilder security (google windows update minitool wilder security)